# Server Restart hangs up since threads of SLF4J gets hanged and not killed while server stop

Tags: server, log4j, websphere, slf4j

After my java application is deployed on websphere application servers, the server restart hangs up the process.

So far, the analysis of the data shows that the application is not completely stopping during the stopping of the application server.  This causes the JVM to not stop until it's terminated.  The reason for this is that during the stopping of the application, the Quartz scheduler is trying to performing some log4j logging and becomes stuck and/or blocked.

Here is the portion of the logs where it seems the log4j threads hang up instead of terminating:

### pstack data (Thread# 96)

```
...
...
JVM_MonitorWait (0, 1012d16b8, 7d0, 1012d1000, 1a1, ffffffff7cbfa000) + 270
* org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Ljava/lang/String;)V+15 (line 419)
* org/quartz/simpl/SimpleThreadPool.shutdown(Z)V+184 (line 684)
* org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.shutdown(Z)V+203 (line 1324)
* org/quartz/impl/StdScheduler.shutdown(Z)V+5 (line 414)
*org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.destroy()V+19(line 1535)
...
...
```

The only work around my team has to manually stop the JVM and start the application server back.

This does not happen when I restart server locally!! although locally I get following error in console while restarting my websphere server:

```
[5/10/16 14:00:20:700 CDT] 00000010 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [becEar#becWeb.war]:.Initializing log4j from [classpath:com/baxter/bec/config/log4j-dvl.xml]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:949 CDT] 00000010 SystemOut     O [2016-05-10 14:00:20,949] DEBUG com.baxter.bec.web.utility.StartupListener initializing context... 
[5/10/16 14:00:20:949 CDT] 00000010 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -      [becEar#becWeb.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://219.fwk-1438711063:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/becWeb/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:700 CDT] 00000010 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [becEar#becWeb.war]:.Initializing log4j from [classpath:com/baxter/bec/config/log4j-dvl.xml]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:949 CDT] 00000010 SystemOut     O [2016-05-10 14:00:20,949] DEBUG com.baxter.bec.web.utility.StartupListener initializing context... 
[5/10/16 14:00:20:949 CDT] 00000010 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [becEar#becWeb.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://219.fwk-1438711063:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/becWeb/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[5/10/16 14:00:20:684 CDT] 00000010 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

enter code here
Could this be the problem? I am using Websphere version V8.0- 8.0.0.8
JVM version - 1.6_64

Kindly help if anybody has the possible solution to this!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which version of slf4j-api.jar and slf4j-log4j12.jar do you have on your classpath? Which version of Quartz?

Comment: In any case, you also need to identify the monitor being held which I think is key to the problem at hand.